# Moment generating function problem with integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I have a random variable $X$ with density function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=Nx^{-\alpha}e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation}
To continue with the main part of the exercise I am working on I need to compute the moment generating function of this random variable. So I note that
\begin{equation}
M_{X}(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{tx}Nx^{-\alpha}e^{-x}dx
\end{equation}
If I for example use Wolfram Alpha it becomes clear to me that this integral does not exist and when applying integration by parts it becomes a huge mess for me. Does anyone know if I am making a mistake or how to compute this integral?

Comment: Think about the incomplete gamma function. It should converge if $t<1$